# Acessando lista do ViewBag via Javascript

Tags: javascript, índices

Estou tentando acessar os elementos de uma lista armazenada no ViewBag da seguinte maneira:

```
function equipamentoTemControle() {

   for(i = 0; i < @ViewBag.qtdEquipamentos; i++) {

      var contratocod = @ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos[i].contratocod;
   }

}
```

Porém ao tentar acessar o atributo ***contratocod*** do indice ***i*** o Visual Studio diz que a variável i não existe. Como devo acessar ?

Comment: Não devia ser `qtdEquipamentos[i].contratocod;` em vez de `DadosEquipamentos[i].contratocod;`?

Comment: Não, pois ViewBag.qtdEquipamentos é um número inteiro, e ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos é a lista que eu quero acessar.

Comment: Mas a array é `qtdEquipamentos` certo? Nesse caso talvez seja `qtdEquipamentos[i].DadosEquipamentos.contratocod`?

Comment: Não. qtdEquipamentos é só um numero inteiro. A array é DadosEquipamentos

Comment: O que dá `alert(typeof @ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos);`?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SCO.Models.EquipamentosModel]

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido.

```
var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos));

for(i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {

    var contratocod = jsonObj[i].contratocod;
}
```